# Managing Committed RAM % in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, memory, image-service

I have a server with 16GB of RAM, and it's holding roughly 156 Image Services.

Managing the % of committed bytes in use, I am using roughly 83%. Or about 13.28 GB.

The server is now kicking out some of the Image Services, and when I try to restart/add them back, I get errors.

Does the server really need 2.7 GB of breathing room?

Are there ways to get around this without using 2 CPUs or increasing RAM again?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  How much swap is on the system?  What operating system?  How have you determined how much RAM you're using?

Comment: Error: Error handling service request : 0x80004005 - Invalid input data source path:

Comment: Error Code: 500

The path is not invalid, I have checked the mosaic datasets that link and they are not broken.. Not are the path's different from that of the Image Service

Comment: I am monitoring RAM using a Remote desktop to server manager, looking at the performance monitor of our server.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro
Service Pack 1

64-bitOS

Comment: While this isn't an answer to your question, there is a LOT of information on memory usage with AGS here that I'd read through: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/66224-10.1-Memory-Issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using my W7 box as a virtual terminal (Outlook + Firefox + 2 PuTTY sessions) and it's using 2.5Gb of 4Gb (4200Gb swap).  Squeezing the last bit of RAM out of any Windows box will always be a challenge.  Even if you run up the swap to (physical + 4Gb) you're unlikely to get much more out of this system (if you actually start utilizing swap, performance will drop 4-5 *orders of magnitude*).

Comment: So is the server rejecting Image Services so it can maintain a certain amount of RAM for processing?
I just don't want to bother IT for more memory if it's not needed...
There are other efficient ways to go about storing these data, however this setup is how the client requested it unfortunately.  So we now have to work around the technical aspects to make it work.

Comment: No, no application will ever reserve RAM for an OS.  The OS is generating errors that are causing registration to fail.  At that point, the possibility of other services failing on occasion increases (just due to the ebb and flow of heap management, much less the possibility of memory leaks).

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to pull this off by doing some tuning on your ArcGIS for Server without increasing the RAM.

**1. Process Low Isolation**

Using process low isolation instead of high isolation might be an
efficient solution. This will make you run your image services with
much less RAM. This will basically squeeze multiple instances into a
single process.

To change this parameter, from the ArcGIS Server Manager, click *Services*. Then edit the service you want to modify the process isolation properties. Activate the *Processes* tab and change the *Isolation Settings* to Low Process Isolation. You can also specify how many instances can run in a single process thus saving more memory.

[image: Isolation]

**2. Configure the Services with fewer Instances**

You can minimize the maximum number of instances in the pooling options
for services. This way you will have fewer instances which consume
less memory. You can also increase the waiting time for the users. let them wait for                    free instances instead of handing them new ones and wasting your memory.

[image]

**3. Don't start up instances that are rarely used.**

Image instances that are rarely used does not require to be initiated from the start. Set the minimum number of instances for those services to zero to save up some more memory.

[image]